# '</div' injected in Classic ASP html response, page continues to load

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

So, this is weird.

We have a `2008 R2 server` and `Win 7x64 dev` workstations running **Classic ASP**.

One page in the site, at exactly `carat position 98301`, a `</div` is being inserted into the source.  Notice it's **not** a fully closing div (`</div>`) tag.  Just `</div` .

So, all sorts of things are breaking since it moves around, based on other things that modify the page (user permissions, querystring values, etc).  But always exactly at `position 98301` in the code.  And always only on this one page.

I've never seen this before and have no idea where to figure out what's doing it.  We have many other pages with hundreds of thousands of characters that are fine.  We have shorter pages, too.  All the IIS settings are the same for all pages and include a `4Mb response buffer` and both `static and dynamic compression` enabled (which I togged both ways without change).  We also have 3 `source control branches` and this is happening in them all, only on this one page.

We are using 2 `Win7x64 dev workstations`, 1 `Win2008R2 local test server` and 1 `Win2008R2 prod server`, and they all do exactly the same thing.

I've moved around the code some, cut out functions, added new code in there to loop `Hello World`, and no matter what I do, it always inserts just `</div` at exactly `carat position 98301`.

I can't think of anything else to test.  All suggestions are welcome!  Thank you!

Comment: **Update:** fiddling more with include files and stripping out non-essential code, the `</div` is now moving around from `position 98301` to other places roughly between `position 80000` and `position 115000`.  I have regex searched the solution for `</div[^>]` with zero results.  Still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the combination of `htmlEncode()` and `htmlDecode()` being on the page, and was only a problem in Chrome (currently v39.x).  Firefox and IE worked fine.  On our page we had about a 600 line script block, and `htmlEncode()` and `htmlDecode()` were close to the top of the block.  By moving them to immediately before the `</script>` tag everything worked and `</div` was not being injected.  While I was not the author of that page, I can see the `htmlEncode()` and `htmlDecode()` functions were sourced from here: [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/html-encoding-in-javascript-jquery)

Additionally, we have both Prototype (1.7.1) and jQuery (1.11.x) loaded, and jQuery loading as `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` before Prototype.  Changing `return $('<div/>')....` to `return $j('<div/>')....` and even `return jQuery('<div/>')....` had absolutely no affect on the situation.

I still do not know WHY this was happening, but it has been resolved (for now, anyway) by moving the functions to the bottom of the script tag.